# How to make queries on nested lists with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, subquery

## Context

I have a legacy mongodb with 4 collections (see models below). And my goal here is to query all `observation` that have **at least one** metadata that has the field `is_valid` set to false and the `observation.results.stitched.model_outputs.results.predictions.metadata.created_at` between 2 dates. By *"at least one"*, I mean that if an observation has one of its model's output prediction that fits those 2 requirements, it should return the observation along with all its model outputs and predictions for those model outputs.

## Models

observation collection:

```
  _id: ObjectId("abcd-1234"),
  created_at:2022-04-28T11:14:20.002+00:00,
  status: "persisted",
  results: {
    stitched: {
      full_image: "https://www.path_to_image.com",
      model_outputs: [
        ObjectId("abcs-1243"),
        ObjectId("abce-1247")
      ]
    }
  } 
}
```

model_output collection:

```
  _id: ObjectId("abcs-1243"),
  created_at:2022-04-28T11:14:20.002+00:00,
  status: "persisted",
  results: {
    raw_predictions: "https://www.path_to_large_array.com",
    binary_mark: "https://www.path_to_binary_mask.com",
    predictions: [
      ObjectId("wbcs-124e"),
      ObjectId("awds-234e"),
      ObjectId("jnla-1233"),
      ...,
      ObjectId("jawd-1039")
    ]
  } 
}
```

prediction collection:

```
  _id: ObjectId("wbcs-124e"),
  created_at:2022-04-28T11:14:20.002+00:00,
  status: "persisted",
  area: 21484060.5,
  perimeter: 1640.724417686462,
  bounding_box: [
    39,
    281,
    630,
    602
  ],
  max_width: 5751,
  max_height: 3871,
  metadata: [
    ObjectId("mwao-1243"),
    ObjectId("lksk-8293"),
    ObjectId("psdk-1293")
  ]
}
```

metadata collection (it's like a history of all human annotation on a model prediction):

```
  _id: ObjectId("mwao-1243"),
  created_at:2022-04-29T14:10:29.122+00:00,
  status: "persisted",
  type: "human label",
  is_valid: false,
  comment: "this prediction is a mistake"
}
```

## Current Solution

My current solution is to set an `observation_id` field on the metadata collection to track the parent observation. Then I could query the metadata collection and then get a list of `observation_id` to then query the nested objects with an aggregation pipeline. I'd prefer a single monster query than 2 queries, since adding the `observation_id` would be redundant.

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yCHTiK9G8xR) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand correctly, you need three `$lookup`s and then `$filter` and `$match`. This will bring all the data and create a field `matchingDocs` that counts the number of metadata docs that fits the needs on each observation doc. Then just match the observation docs that have more than 0 matchingDocs. For example:

```
db.observation.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "model_output",
      localField: "results.stitched.model_outputs",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "model_outputs"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "prediction",
      localField: "model_outputs.results.predictions",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "predictions"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "metadata",
      localField: "predictions.metadata",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "metadata"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      matchingDocs: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$metadata",
            as: "item",
            cond: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$item.is_valid",
                    false
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $gte: [
                    "$$item.created_at",
                    ISODate("2022-04-28T14:10:29.122+00:00")
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $lte: [
                    "$$item.created_at",
                    ISODate("2022-04-30T14:10:29.122+00:00")
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$match: {matchingDocs: {$gt: 0}}},
  {$unset: "matchingDocs"}
])
```

[playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yCHTiK9G8xR)

Comment: The $addFields is a great idea! Really fits my problem here. I'll update the $lookups to I get a nested document in the end but really, the filter works like a charm. Kudos!